# Can we create multiple Amazon DynamoDB tables at a time using AWS CloudFormation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, cicd

I'm trying to create Amazon DynamoDB tables using Cloud Formation Template. So my question is can I have multiple tables created in single go ?

If yes, what would the approach be, to have multiple "Properties" or to have multiple "Resources" ?

Can you please clarify on this.

Comment: Resources, obviously.

Comment: Warning!!!! This will delete all tables if you delete the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each DynamoDB table is a resource of type AWS::DynamoDB::Table.

Add multiple resources, each with a different table name. For example:

```
Resources:
  Users:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: UserID
        AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: UserID
        KeyType: HASH
  Jobs:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: UserID
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: JobID
        AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: UserID
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: JobID
        KeyType: RANGE
```